# What is the alternate to PasswordDigest when clear text password is not stored on the web-service producer?

Tags: security, web-services, passwords, wss, wss4j

**Scenario:**

Web-service producer have only SHA-1 hash of passwords stored in database. We need to authenticate Web-service users using User Name/Password combination.

---

**[Web Services Security UsernameToken Profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf)** allows us to add soap headers for this purpose:

> The  element is
>   introduced in the WSS: SOAP Message
>   Security documents as a way of
>   providing a username.
>
> Within  element, a
>    element may be
>   specified. Passwords of type
>   PasswordText and PasswordDigest are
>   not limited to actual passwords,
>   although this is a common case.
>   [(146-151)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf)

PasswordText password type means that password is sent over the wire as plain text which is a security issue if we are not using Transport Level Security mechanisms. PasswordDigest avoids sending plain text passwords and sends a hash. But to avoid replay attack (i-e attacker using wiretap to capture the hashed password and resend it with another request) the PasswordDigest adds a timestamp and a random number to password before computing the hash. This addition results in following restriction:

> Note that PasswordDigest can only
>   be used if the plain text password (or
>   password equivalent) is available
>   to both the requestor and the
>   recipient. [(196-197)](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/v1.1/wss-v1.1-spec-os-UsernameTokenProfile.pdf)

---

But in our case we do not have plain text password. 
My question is: what alternates do we have other that to make plain text passwords available on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SHA-1 can be perfectly used as a "plaintext" password.

- Ask the user the password
- convert it to SHA-1
- run it throught the PasswordDigest thing
- the server will do the same with the SHA-1 in the database
- the server will find that they match and allow access

Comment: I guess you are right. Perhaps this is what they meant with "password equivalent" in the specs

Comment: That's exactly what "password equivalent" is used to mean in these contexts - same uniqueness, same (or better) level of inscrutability.